# Invalid setting for parameter 'Gain'

Tags: simulink

I am trying to create a simple controller, but keep receiving an error for the gain block stating that there is an undefined variable 'u'. I do not understand Simulink well and I am just trying to replicate an old homework problem right now. The code I have here was provided as a solution, but I still receive the error when I try to run it. Any insights as to what might be going on?

```
I= 10; Wl= 5; k= 2; J= 1; 
%set initial conditions
thetaIC= 0; phiIC= 0; x0= zeros(4,1); 
%fix theta= 0, check output
[xe, ue]= trim('Ex3_System',x0,0,x0,1)  
[A,B,~,~]= linmod('Ex3_System', xe, ue) 
%choose your desired poles 
p= linspace(-1.2,-1.5,4) 
%recall the minus sign
K= -acker(A,B,p) 
%perturb initial condition 
thetaIC= deg2rad(5); 
sim('Ex3_Controller');
```

[image]
[image]

> Invalid setting in 'Ex3_Controller/Gain' for parameter 'Gain'. Caused
>   by:
>       Error using hw12 (line 57)
>       Error evaluating parameter 'Gain' in 'Ex3_Controller/Gain'
>           Error using hw12 (line 57)
>           Undefined function or variable 'u'.
>               Error using hw12 (line 57)
>               Variable 'u' does not exist.
>               Suggested Actions:
>                   • Load a file into 'Base Workspace'. - Fix
>                   • Create a new variable. - Fix

Update: After removing the `u` term from the `gain` block, I received a different error:

> Error using hw12 (line 57)
>       Error in port widths or dimensions. Output port 1 of 'Ex3_Controller/Gain' is a one dimensional vector with 4 elements.
>       Error using hw12 (line 57)
>       Error in port widths or dimensions. Input port 1 of 'Ex3_Controller/Model1' is a one dimensional vector with 1 elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Gain` block takes the value of the input signal and multiplies it by the value of the gain.  In your case the gain is `K` and that is all you need to put into the gain block (i.e. remove the `*u`, Simulink handles that for you.)

Once that is done, the dimension error you are getting is because your controller requires `u` to be a scalar, but you are feeding a 4 element vector into it.  You need to change the appropriate parameter of the `Gain` block so that it does a matrix multiplication, taking the 4-by-1 matrix `K` and (matrix) multiplying it with the 4 element "out" signal to produce a scalar.

Comment: Thank you for the response! After removing the `*u` from the gain block, I received a new error. I've uploaded the model of the system being used in the controller as well if this is any help, and also updated my question with the new error I'm receiving upon doing so

Comment: I figured out the issue. After removing the `*u` I needed to change the operation type to matrix multiplication. Upon doing so, the gain block automatically adds the `*u`, making it appear as if this was the original gain block. Thank you!